# Filling out two columns in Excel with first and last day of the month respectively

Tags: vba, excel

I would like code which will fill out columns A and B with the first and last day of the current month. It should look somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Upload your code attempt

Comment: I wasn't able to put together any code so far which automatically inputs date values. I was only able to make a work-around with a input box for the user to input the starting and end date manually and then the code simply copies this value to as many cells as possible.

I am not even sure if it is possible with VBA to do what I am asking for without any work-arounds. :/

Comment: Sure it is possible. See my answer below. Just generate the fist and last date and copy them down as you did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 functions to find the first and last day of a month. To fill out the columns should be easy then.

```
Function dhFirstDayInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
    ' Return the first day in the specified month.
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
    End If
    dhFirstDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate), 1)
End Function


Function dhLastDayInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
    ' Return the last day in the specified month.
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
    End If
    dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)
End Function
```

Source: [Finding the Beginning or End of a Month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227522(v=vs.60).aspx)

To get the first/last month dates from other month than the current you can make use of the [`DateAdd()`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) for the input date:

```
lastDayOfLastMonth = dhLastDayInMonth(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))
firstDayOfLastMonth = dhFirstDayInMonth(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Just one follow-up question: is it possible to change it so it gives me the values of the past month? So instead of giving me current month's first and last day can it give me these values for last month? Would subtracting 1 from dtmDate do that?

Comment: I added an example to get the last day from the month before